# Why are CMake variables case-sensitive but commands are not?

Tags: cmake, case-sensitive

Popular languages such as C, C++, python, ksh are always case-sensitive for both variables and functions. So, I'm surprised to learn that CMake treats that differently. What's the reason? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake variables are *case-sensitive*, as in other popular languages. However, the CMake commands are *case-insensitive* for historical reasons, and due to CMake's strict adherence to backwards-compatibility. A [quote](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/77543bde41b0e52c3959016698b529835945d62d) from CMake maintainer, Brad King:

> Ancient CMake versions required upper-case commands.  Later command
>   names became case-insensitive.  Now the preferred style is lower-case.

indicates that CMake commands *used* to be upper-case. However, the convention now is to use **lower-case** commands.

Many behaviors and conventions from older versions of CMake have been maintained (and aged-out) using CMake policies. The [`cmake_policy`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_policy.html) command gives developers control over whether the *old* or *new* behavior should be used. However, as far as I know, there is no policy dictating case-sensitivity for CMake commands.